# (Completely hypothetical) Ring passing through a black hole

Tags: black-holes

(I know this is going to sound odd just please consider it)

What if you were to throw an indestructible ring straight into a black hole with a hole larger than it's singularity?

Would its trajectory be straight through the black hole missing the singularity? If this is the case then wouldn't it reach escape velocity and as result break the speed of light?

Think of it like a ball rolling down a hill and being able to speed up enough to roll back up a hill of the same height.

I understand that a black hole achieves it's event horizon through distortion of space time so what I am truly pondering is if it would have a straight and un-impeded trajectory through the black hole.

Comment: What we learn from this thought experiment is that an indestructible ring can’t exist.

Comment: Everything you throw into a black hole comes back out, again. It simply takes a very, very long time for it to come back out.

Comment: Mike, was I not clear enough with expressing this was hypothetical? Thats not what I was asking.

Comment: @idk But your hypothetical scenario changes the way that black holes work in ways that you’ve not specified other than to say that a ring is indestructible, and so your question can’t be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem with this question is that nothing is truly indestructible, especially when facing the extreme environment that is the interior of a black hole. Realistically, any ring (no matter how rigid) will experience tidal forces as it approaches the singularity. These tidal forces will crush the ring down while the gradient of the gravitational pull forces it into a long string (spaghettification). This isn't just a matter of pedantry in that "of course no real material is indestructible", but that any material is going to be made from constituent parts, and those parts will each individually be pulled towards the singularity.

I also want to address one other issue with your question. There are no trajectories inside a black hole that can miss the singularity. All possible futures point there. That is, once you pass the event horizon, there is absolutely no possible path you could take, no matter how fast you go, that will result in you never reaching the singularity. In fact, while you can delay reaching the singularity to some extent, fighting too hard will actually make you reach it faster.

Comment: I never noticed this before, but the old saying that all roads lead to Rome might have an actual physical background.

Comment: I very much appreciate your response, though I am still wondering if it would be possible to escape the black hole (in a timely manner) if it did manage to pass by the singularity without colliding with it. I understand that it shouldn't be possible, I am asking purely out of curiosity.

Comment: @idk There are no paths that an object inside a black hole can take to escape it. Even if you managed to miss the singularity on the first pass, and even if you are traveling faster than light (ignoring that doing so is impossible in its own right) - you can not escape. It's not simply that the gravity there is "really strong", but that space and time switch roles in a sense, and that all possible futures point inwards to the singularity.